# Devise finding user by reset token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-recoverable

I'm trying to make an api for resetting password, I made devise handle the part when the user press on `forgot password` and sending him an email with a token but I tried to change it in the other part I needed to look up user using that token when he reset his password but Devise `reset_password_token` of the user (in the DB) is not like the token sent in the email, I only receive `token, password, password_confirmation` to make that API work, So I need to find that user using `token` sent in the email(User.where(reset_password_token: TOKEN)), Is there a way to convert token in the email to the one I have in the DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check the `reset_password_by_token` class method which contains the logic. But you can use it directly:

```
User.reset_password_by_token({
  reset_password_token: token,
  password: password,
  password_confirmation: password_confirmation
})
```

Link to current [master code here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L145)

Comment: Thanks dude, I swear I've read it twice but I didn't focus properly, Thank you very much.

Comment: glad it helped ;)

Comment: Actually if you want to find the User without reset his password you can use `User.with_reset_password_token(token)` (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/032c4476aeaf8eacd96331e37ba758cbae0f6248/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L125)